# Everytime I Try To Login To Ubuntu Mate, I have to boot from recovery mode, how do I fix this?

Tags: grub2, data-recovery

When I shut down and turn my laptop back on, it boots into GRUB settings, and the only way I could get back to Ubuntu is to << Advanced Ubuntu Settings << Ubuntu  (recovery) and it takes at least 5 minutes to boot. Please help, or find someone who can!

Comment: If you have to boot into recovery mode sounds like something happened before that you're not mentioning...

Comment: Please could post an image, and how long do you wait for it to boot before going into _advanced ubuntu settings_ ?